# Polly won't throw on some exceptions?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, polly

I'm using Polly with .net Core. My `ConfigureServices` is :

```
private static void ConfigureServices()
{
    var collection = new ServiceCollection();
    var timeoutPolicy = Policy.TimeoutAsync<HttpResponseMessage>(3);  
    collection.AddHttpClient<INetworkService, NetworkService>(s=>
             {
                   s.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://google.com:81"); //this is a deliberate timeout url
             })
    .AddPolicyHandler((a,b)=>GetRetryPolicy(b))
    .AddPolicyHandler(timeoutPolicy); ;
    ...
}
```

This is the `GetRetryPolicy` function:

```
private static IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> GetRetryPolicy(HttpRequestMessage req)
{
    return HttpPolicyExtensions
        .HandleTransientHttpError()
        .OrResult(msg => httpStatusCodesWorthRetrying.Contains(msg.StatusCode))  // see below
        .Or<TimeoutRejectedException>()
        .Or<TaskCanceledException>()
        .Or<OperationCanceledException>()
        .WaitAndRetryAsync(3, retryAttempt =>
        {
            return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
        }, onRetry: (response, delay, retryCount, context) =>
        {

            Console.WriteLine($"______PollyAttempt_____ retryCount:{retryCount}__FOR_BaseUrl_{req.RequestUri.ToString()}");
        });
}
```

Those are the httpcodes I want to retry  :

```
static HttpStatusCode[] httpStatusCodesWorthRetrying = {
   HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout, // 408
   HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, // 500
   HttpStatusCode.BadGateway, // 502
   HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable, // 503
   HttpStatusCode.GatewayTimeout // 504
};
```

Ok. And this is the actual invocation :

```
public async Task Work()
    {

        try
        {
            
            HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("");
            Console.WriteLine("After work");

        }
        catch (TimeoutRejectedException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("inside TimeoutRejectedException");
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("inside catch main http");
        }
}
```

The output is :

> _*****PollyAttempt***** retryCount:1__FOR_BaseUrl_http://google.com:81/
> _*****PollyAttempt***** retryCount:2__FOR_BaseUrl_http://google.com:81/
> _*****PollyAttempt***** retryCount:3__FOR_BaseUrl_http://google.com:81/
> inside  TimeoutRejectedException

(notice it throws) Which is OK. Because Polly throws after this invalid URL is timeout.

But if I change the `http://google.com:81/` to an "internal server error" url : (this return 500)

https://run.mocky.io/v3/9f1b4c18-2cf0-4303-9136-bb67d54d0148

Then it doesn't throw but continues :

> _*****PollyAttempt***** retryCount:1__FOR_BaseUrl_https://run.mocky.io/v3/9f1b4c18-2cf0-4303-9136-bb67d54d0148
> _*****PollyAttempt***** retryCount:2__FOR_BaseUrl_https://run.mocky.io/v3/9f1b4c18-2cf0-4303-9136-bb67d54d0148
> _*****PollyAttempt***** retryCount:3__FOR_BaseUrl_https://run.mocky.io/v3/9f1b4c18-2cf0-4303-9136-bb67d54d0148
> After work

(notice "after work" at the end)

**Question:**

Why does Polly throw at timeout, But doesn't throw at another condition ?
I explictly wrote : `.OrResult(msg => httpStatusCodesWorthRetrying.Contains(msg.StatusCode))` 
and 500 is one of them.

Comment: Check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50835992/check-string-content-of-response-before-retrying-with-polly) helps.

Comment: The whole `OrResult` part is not needed. The `HandleTransientFailure` [covers](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly.Extensions.Http/blob/master/src/Polly.Extensions.Http/HttpPolicyExtensions.cs#L12) 408 and 5xx status codes.

Comment: I'm not sure about the `TimeoutRejectedException` was handled in the correct way as well. In the `Work` you are catching it and that means Retry policy won't be triggered because of `TimeoutRejectedException`.

Comment: @peter after all attempts were tried without success ,polly throws timedoutexception. Imho

Comment: @RoyiNamir Yes, because you have an outer / global timeout policy. In other words the timeout will be your outer policy and the retry will be the inner.

Comment: @peter so was i doing something wrong in trying to catch timeout? What will be the correct code?

Comment: @RoyiNamir It depends. You can define local / per request timeout and you can define one global timeout. In the latter case the timeout includes all requests (the initial attempt + retry attempts + penalties between retries)

Comment: @RoyiNamir [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62918314/13268855) I have detailed the difference between the two kinds of timeout if you want to better understand.

Comment: @Peter im sorry , i might be dumb here. But in my first example i do get timeout after all 3 attempts including first attempt has failed. So ill be happy if you can kindly post an answer to show me what im doing wrong. Goal : throw after all attempts were failed (timeout or 5xx,480)

Comment: @RoyiNamir I remembered that the handler registration order working in the other way around (firstly registered will be the inner...). Sorry, I was wrong. Firstly registered will be the utmost outer. I usually use `PolicyWrap` to avoid this kind of confusion.

Comment: @RoyiNamir I've left a post to make it clear how does the two examples differ from each other. I hope it gives you clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior. A delegate invocation results in either an exception or a return value. When the Polly retries are done, then it propagates whatever result was last, whether it is an exception or a return value.

In this case, the response would have a 500 status code.

Answer (score 3):

As @StephenCleary said that's how the Polly works.

First let me share with you the cleaned up version of your code
then I will give you some explanation about the observed behaviours.

`ConfigureServices`

```
var timeoutPolicy = Policy.TimeoutAsync<HttpResponseMessage>(3,
    onTimeoutAsync: (_, __, ___) => {
        Console.WriteLine("Timeout has occured");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
});

services.AddHttpClient<INetworkService, NetworkService>(
    client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://httpstat.us/500"))
.AddPolicyHandler((_, request) => Policy.WrapAsync(GetRetryPolicy(request), timeoutPolicy));
```

`GetRetryPolicy`

```
private static IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> GetRetryPolicy(HttpRequestMessage req)
    => HttpPolicyExtensions
        .HandleTransientHttpError()
        .Or<TimeoutRejectedException>()
        .Or<OperationCanceledException>()
        .WaitAndRetryAsync(3,
            _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3),
            onRetry: (_, __, retryCount, ___) =>
                Console.WriteLine($"POLLY retryCount:{retryCount} baseUrl: {req.RequestUri}"));
```

---

#### Example `http://google.com:81`

1. Initial request has been sent out
2. No response has been received under 3 seconds
3. Timeout Policy triggered
4. `TimeoutRejectedException` is thrown
5. Retry policy is aware of that exception, so it triggers
6. Retry policy issues 3 seconds penalty
7. Retry policy issues a new request
8. No response has been received under 3 seconds
9. ...
   n. Retry policy is aware of that exception, but it has reached the max retry count
   n+1. Retry throws the exception that it could not handle, so in this case the `TimeoutRejectedException`

#### Example `https://httpstat.us/500`

1. Initial request has been sent out
2. A response with status code 500 has received under 3 seconds
3. Retry policy is aware of that status code, so it triggers
4. Retry policy issues 3 seconds penalty
5. Retry policy issues a new request
6. response with status code 500 has received under 3 seconds
7. ...
   n. Retry policy is aware of that status code, but it has reached the max retry count
   n+1. Retry returns with that response that it could not handle, so in this case the 500

Because there is a lack of `EnsureSuccessStatusCode` method call that's why no exception is being thrown.

As you can see in the second example the TimeoutPolicy is not triggered at all.

Comment: BTW I must tell you that in my project we've built an AUTH docker api. and we made it fully REST. ( 200,409 (conflict) , 401.... etc etc....) and when we added Polly , I got hit by those non success code. I couldn't event do "EnsureSuccessCode" ( I konow it's not polly's but....). This is the last time I build pure REST api. next times I will return 200 and sub codes.

Comment: That's perfectly fine, I just mentioned `EnsureSuccessStatusCode` because it throws exception if status code is above 299. So, if you want to break the happy path then that's the easiest way.

Comment: See also [http-error-codes-are-retried-by-polly-net-by-default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54699826/what-http-error-codes-are-retried-by-polly-net-by-default)